# Can a super class method override a sub class method?

Tags: java, oop

I know that a sub class can override a super class method but can it work the other way around?

Comment: Where would this be useful?

Comment: "Override allows a subclass or child class to provide a specific implementation of a method that is already provided by one of its superclasses or parent classes."  So by definition no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: **No**

There's no reason why this should exist.
If you have a superclass method that you **want** to use, then you simply **don't implement an override** for it in your subclass. If you **don't want** to use the superclass' implementation, then you **write your override** in a subclass.

Answer (score 2):

No, it cannot work the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

No

A subclass is aware of existence of the superclass but a superclass is not aware of all its subclasses. 
Assuming, overriding is possible it would lead to lot of issues. How would you resolve which method needs to be called subclass or superclass?
I believe you should go through the OOP principles to understand better.